# Make two values in a cell sortable

Tags: excel, field, jquery-ui-sortable

Can I make two values in a cell sortable?

I need it to be in the same cell.
Is it possible to write such. like "VALUE1"; "VALUE2" or something like VALUE1 | VALUE2?

I want the list to be:

- A
- B
- C
- D
- E
- F
- ...

and not

- AB
- C
- D
- E
- F
- ...

See the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe Excel treats all data in a cell as one data. It does not recognize whitespace as a separation of data.

Your best bet is to split A and B into 2 cells then vertically merge all cells to the right, column-by-column.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX3h5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get you correctly, but if you want to filter just for cells containing an "A" you can use a Textfilter. You can pick a "containing" Filter and there you can define which letter or string you want to search for.

This would then show only cells containing an A:

- AB
- A
- ABC
- ...

If you only want to display the letter "A" when searching for it and hide the "B" from the same cell, I don't think this is possible.